# Extern variable in header file not linked properly to source file where it is defined

Tags: c, header, linker, extern

Problem: A variable 'VarOriginal' is defined in source C file under pragma say 'parameterX' and declared as an extern variable in a header file under the same pragma 'parameterX'. There is a process using it in which it is known that the variable is shown declared in some other header file where this variable is not present at all.

As a Workaround:I declared one more different variable 'VarNew' before the pragma 'parameterX' in the header file and similarly defined the variable 'VarNew' before the line where 'VarOriginal' was defined. And it all worked.

#### Header file: `header_file_with_problem.h`

```
#ifndef HEADER_FILE_WITH_PROBLEM_H

#define HEADER_FILE_WITH_PROBLEM_H

#include "ABC.h"
```

*declare variable 'VarNew' here* <------

```
#pragma BSS(".parameterX")

extern int VarOriginal;

#pragma BSS(DEFAULT_SECTION_BSS)
```

#### Source C File:

```
#define  HEADER_FILE_WITH_PROBLEM_C

#include "XYZ.h"

#include "header_file_with_problem.h"
```

*declare variable 'VarNew' here* <------

```
#pragma BSS(".parameterX")

int VarOriginal;

#pragma BSS(DEFAULT_SECTION_BSS)
```

But I am not able to understand why the problem was coming earlier. Why was the linker not able to find the definition of 'VarOriginal' in the source file and now it is able to do so, after declaring another variable before 'VarOriginal' itself?

Also, this problem is not with all source and header files present in the folder, but only a few of them.

Comment: You should show a minimal example. You don't even mention _what_ pragma. That is relevant info. We are not psychic, we're just humans

Comment: Also, please edit your post to use meaningful variable names. `A variable "A"... and pragma say "X" and a "B" before "A" and "J" and say "C" and maybe "Y" or "Z"` reads like nonsense and makes it very hard to understand your actual problem. Also remember that we can't see your monitor from here; the only information we have is what you provide us. The more clearly and concisely you can state your question, the more likely you'll get help quickly.

Comment: How did pragma even creep in here at all? The question was about some variable that was extern.

Comment: @PeteWilson Probably because the OP is using `#pragma once` instead of regular multiple inclusion guards

Comment: Oh, yes. That must be it. But that would cause the problem he's seeing, right?

Comment: Sp, where are your variable definitions??? All I see in your code is non-defining declarations. `extern int VarOriginal;` does not define anything, regardless of which file you place it in. Where are the definitions?

Comment: The outline header file is missing its closing `#endif`.  Why can't you show us how you are declaring your variables?  And why are you messing with the `#pragma` about BSS?  Does it make any difference if you remove or comment out those lines?  What platform are you developing on/for?  The systems that seem to use something similar (Google '#pragma bss') do not seem to use exactly the shown notation, but do seem to be for embedded systems.

Comment: I have provided the definitions. But the problem is still there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't see anything *defined* in your source file. The

```
extern int VarOriginal;
```

is still a *non-defining* declaration, regardless of where you put it (source file or header file). There's not a single variable definition in your code sample, so no wonder the linker is complaining about missing definitions.

In order to *define* a variable in your C file you need to do either

```
int VarOriginal; /* no `extern` !!! */
```

or add an explicit initializer

```
extern int VarOriginal = 0; /* definition */
```

A mere

```
extern int VarOriginal; /* not a definition!!! */
```

that you seem to have there now (according to what you posted) is not a definition.

Comment: Thank you.. this was useful to me. But I have already used int VarOriginal; in the source file. I have corrected that in my question above.

Comment: Hmmm...which compiler(s) accept `extern int VarOriginal = 0; /* definition */`?  You can't mix an initializer with `extern`.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: Why not? Since the beginning of time it was perfectly legal to mix an initializer with `extern`. `extern` can be used with both *declarations* and *definitions*. Speaking informally, when used with *declarations* (non-defining ones) it has "import" semantics. When used with *definitions* it has "export" semantics. In this case `extern int VarOriginal = 0;` is a definition (because of the initializer) and `extern` explicitly gives it external linkage ("exports" it).

Comment: This `extern` is, of course, redundant, since the object would have external linkage by default. But it is not illegal. Some compilers believe that `extern` should be (or "usually is") reserved for variable *declarations* only. They assume that user made a mistake by adding `extern` to a variable definition and issue a warning for that (GCC does, for one example). But nevertheless formally it is not an error.

Comment: Which beginning of time?  FWIW, `clang` (Apple LLVM version 6.1.0 (clang-602.0.53) (based on LLVM 3.6.0svn)) on Mac OS X objects with: `xx.c:1:12: warning: 'extern' variable has an initializer [-Wextern-initializer]
extern int VarOriginal = 0; /* definition */`.  That was a plain `clang -c xx.c`.  I'm surprised that's only a warning — it was always a violation of the standard.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: It was *never* a violation of the standard. Nowhere in the standard it is prohibited. For example, there's no fundamental difference between applying `extern` to function definition or to variable definition. Or do you believe `extern` applied to function definition is illegal as well? The most likely reason for the warning is explained in my comment above.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler: An example of `extern` variable declaration with an initializer is given in C89/90 **6.7.2 External object definitions**. It is carried over without any changes all the way into C11. Frankly, this is quite surprising to see anyone question it.

Comment: Well, I have to concede that I spent some time trying to find the wording that prohibited it, but didn't find it.  It is somewhat surprising to me that the compiler generates a default warning like that when the standard does not prohibit it.  But I didn't find anything that contradicts what you're saying.  I'd look askance at the code — like the compiler does — but I can't see anything that prohibits it.

Comment: And (as you indicate) there's an example (Example 1) in §6.9.2 in C11, which corresponds to §6.7.2 in C89, with `extern int i = 3;` as valid.  So, the standard definitely indicates it should be OK (even though examples are non-normative).  I'm left puzzling over the compiler warning, even though it can be suppressed.  People are going to come across this, whether we like it or not.  When the Example 1 is cleaned up to omit the two erroneous declarations, `clang` is left jibing at code that the standard indicates is OK.  Not so good.  I wonder if a bug report is in order.